# How can I reduce stringing on very small parts?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, pla, retraction, stringing

I'm trying to print a 30% version of this [High Bypass Engine Nacelle](https://cults3d.com/en/3d-model/gadget/high-bypass-engine-nacelle), but I'm having some quality issues with the high pressure turbine compression stages.

I've uploaded several photos to Imgur [here](https://imgur.com/a/JFDbWB0), ill include some below:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

What's odd is that the stators, which are very similar in size and overhangs, seem to print much better. Here's a photo of that:
[image]
[image]

I have printed several retraction tower tests and selected the best values, but it doesn't seem to improve all that much. Whenever I print larger components, they seem to print just fine with very little or no stringing on the surface.

**Filaments tested**

- [HATCHBOX 1.75mm Silk Bronze PLA](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HXT63P8)
- [AMOLEN Silk PLA Filament, Silver Grey](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BWTFKS5D)
- [AMOLEN Silk PLA Filament, Black](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0C69HXGWW)

**Settings**

- Ender 3 S1 Pro (running klipper)
- Nozzle: 0.4 mm
- Sliced with Cura
- Layer height: 0.2 mm, 0.16 mm
- Print speed: 50 mm/s, 80 mm/s, 100 mm/s
- Walls: 4
- Wall ordering: Inside to Outside (my default), and Outside to Inside
- Top: 3
- Bottom: 3
- Infill (doesn't matter, the walls/top/bottom make it 100%)
- Retraction:

  - Speed: 25 mm/s, 30 mm/s, 35 mm/s
  - Distance: 0.5 mm, 0.8 mm, 1 mm
  - Retract on layer change: Yes
  - Retraction minimum travel: 1.5 mm, 1 mm
- Coasting: Disabled
- Temperature:

  - Extruder: 190 °C, 200 °C, 210 °C, 215 °C
  - Bed: 60 °C
- Wipe:

  - Outer wall: 0.5 mm
  - Infill: 0.1 mm
- Print thin walls: enabled
- Combing: Not in skin

I'm not sure what other settings to share that would help troubleshoot this. If there's more detail that would help, lmk and ill add it.

Comment: IMHO you are pushing to the limits with an affordable economical printer, too small/detailed parts and a too wide nozzle. You could lower the speed, layer height and increase part cooling maybe.

Comment: @oscar - Idk, I've been able to print very tiny screws with very fine threads (I think it was M4, printed at 0.12mm layer height). I don't see how this can be more complicated than that. Especially considering I _can_ print the stators. 
A friend pointed out that it may be due to the volumetric flow rate, it doesn't have room to go very quick, so the filament dwells in the hot end too long and overheats.
Im going to try a print at a lower temperature, again. lol.